# Django: queryset.count() is significantly slower on chained filters than single filters regardless of returned query size--is there a solution?

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, count

EDIT: Best solution thanks to Hakan--

```
queriedForms.filter(pk__in=list(formtype.form_set.all().filter(formrecordattributevalue__record_value__contains=constraint['TVAL'], formrecordattributevalue__record_attribute_type__pk=rtypePK).values_list('pk', flat=True))).count()
```

I tried more of his suggestions but I can't avoid an INNER JOIN--this seems to be a a stable solution that does get me small, but predictable speed increases across the board. Look through his answer for more details!

---

I've been struggling with a problem I haven't seen an answer to online.

When chaining two filters in Django e.g.

```
masterQuery = bigmodel.relatedmodel_set.all()
masterQuery = masterQuery.filter(name__contains="test")
masterQuery.count() 
#returns 100,000 results in < 1 second
#test filter--all 100,000+ names have "test x" where x is 0-9 
storedCount = masterQuery.filter(name__contains="9").count()
#returns ~50,000 results but takes 5-6 seconds
```

Trying a slightly different way:

```
masterQuery = masterQuery.filter(name__contains="9")
masterQuery.count()
#also returns ~50,000 results in 5-6 seconds
```

performing an & merge seems to ever so slightly improve performance, e.g

```
masterQuery = bigmodel.relatedmodel_set.all()
masterQuery = masterQuery.filter(name__contains="test") 
(masterQuery & masterQuery.filter(name__contains="9")).count()
```

It seems as if count takes a significantly longer time beyond a single filter in a queryset.

I assume it may have something to do with mySQL, which apparently doesn't like nested statements--and I assume that two filters are creating a nested query that slows mySQL down, regardless of the  SELECT COUNT(*) django uses

So my question is: Is there anyway to speed this up? I'm getting ready to do a lot of regular nested querying only using queryset counts (I don't need the actual model values) without database hits to load the models. e.g. I don't need to load 100,000 models from the database, I just need to know there are 100,000 there. It's obviously much faster to do this through querysets than len() but even at 5 secs a count when I'm running 40 counts for an entire complex query is 3+ minutes--I'd prefer it be under a minute. Am I just fantasizing or does someone have a suggestion as to how this could be accomplished outside of increasing the server's processor speed?

EDIT: If it's helpful--the time.clock() speed is .3 secs for the chained filter() count--the actual time to console and django view output is 5-6s

EDIT2: To answer any questions about indexing, the filters use both an indexed and non indexed value for each link in the chain:

```
mainQuery = masterQuery = bigmodel.relatedmodel_set.all()
mainQuery = mainQuery.filter(reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_value__contains="test", reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_attribute_type__pk=1)
#Where "record_attribute_type" is another foreign key being used as a filter
mainQuery.count() #produces 100,000 results in < 1sec
mainQuery.filter(reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_value__contains="9", reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_attribute_type__pk=5).count()
#produces ~50,000 results in 5-6 secs
```

So each filter in the chain is functionally similar, it is an AND filter(condition,condition) where one condition is indexed, and the other is not. I can't index both conditions.

Edit 3:
Similar queries that result in smaller results, e.g. < 10,000 are much faster, regardless of the nesting--e.g. the first filter in the chain produces 10,000 results in ~<1sec but the second filter in the chain will produce 5,000 results in ~<1sec

Edit 4:
Still not working based on @Hakan's solution

```
mainQuery = bigmodel.relatedmodel_set.all()
#Setup the first filter as normal
mainQuery = mainQuery.filter(reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_value__contains="test", reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_attribute_type__pk=1)

#Grab a values list for the second chained filter instead of chaining it    
values = bigmodel.relatedmodel_set.all().filter(reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_value__contains="test", reverseforeignkeytestmodel__record_attribute_type__pk=8).values_list('pk', flat=True)
#filter the first query based on the values_list rather than a second filter
mainQuery = mainQuery.filter(pk__in=values)
mainQuery.count()
#Still takes on average the same amount of time after enough test runs--seems to be slightly faster than average--similar to the (quersetA & querysetB) merge solution I tried.
```

It's possible I did this wrong--but the count results are consistent between the new value_list filter technique, e.g. I'm getting the same # of results. So it's definitely working--but seemingly taking the same amount of time

EDIT 5:
Also based on @Hakan's solution with some slight tweaks

```
mainQuery.filter(pk__in=list(formtype.form_set.all().filter(formrecordattributevalue__record_value__contains=constraint['TVAL'], formrecordattributevalue__record_attribute_type__pk=rtypePK).values_list('pk', flat=True))).count()
```

This seems to operate faster for larger results in a queryset, e.g. > 50,000, but is actually much slower on smaller queryset results, e.g. < 50,000--where they used to be <1sec--sometimes 2-3 running in 1 second for chain filtering, they now all take 1 second individually. Essentially the speed gains in the larger queryset have been nullified by the speed loss in the smaller querysets.

I'm still going to try and break up the queries as per his suggestion further--but I'm not sure I'm able to. I'll update again(possibly on Monday) when I figure that out and let everyone interested know the progress.

Comment: Is the column you're filtering by indexed?

Comment: Thanks for asking: Yes and No. I simplified my queries for this example a bit, but essentially each filter has an AND statement filter(indexedValue, nonIndexedValue)  and both filters in the chain are exactly the same format--the second in the chain is just getting a smaller cut of the original queryset. I'll edit the question with a more sensible example of this.

Comment: It might be helpful to inspect the `.query` attribute of your querysets.

Comment: Have you tried the approach suggested in the docs _**Performance considerations** 

Be cautious about using nested queries and understand your database server’s performance characteristics (if in doubt, benchmark!). Some database backends, most notably MySQL, don’t optimize nested queries very well. It is more efficient, in those cases, to extract a list of values and then pass that into the second query. That is, execute two queries instead of one_ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: example code from docs: `values = Blog.objects.filter(
        name__contains='Cheddar').values_list('pk', flat=True)
; entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__in=list(values))`

Comment: @HåkenLid  I'll try this--I'm using a lot of deep relationships--sometimes manytomany. I haven't done a lot of research on .values  or .value_list, but I'm worried that the values will hit the database--which can take a long time to load 100,000 database items(much longer than a count() hit )  Do you know off-hand if that's the case?

Comment: With `values_list` only the relevant column(s) are selected in the db. So it could also be a lot faster than the current inefficient nested query.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual generated SQL.  Your question is best answered by starting in MySQL and working backwards to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, since I don't have a mysql project to test with.

The [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in) contains a section about the performance of nested queries.

> **Performance considerations**
>
> Be cautious about using nested queries and understand your database
>   server’s performance characteristics (if in doubt, benchmark!). Some
>   database backends, most notably MySQL, don’t optimize nested queries
>   very well. It is more efficient, in those cases, to extract a list of
>   values and then pass that into the second query. That is, execute two
>   queries instead of one:
>
> ```
> values = Blog.objects.filter(
>     name__contains='Cheddar').values_list('pk', flat=True) 
> entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__in=list(values))
> ```
>
> Note the list() call around the Blog QuerySet to force execution of the first query.
>   Without it, a nested query would be executed, because QuerySets are
>   lazy.

So, maybe you can improve the performance by trying something like this:

```
masterQuery = bigmodel.relatedmodel_set.all()
pks = list(masterQuery.filter(name__contains="test").values_list('pk', flat=True))
count = masterQuery.filter(pk__in=pks, name__contains="9")
```

Since your initial MySQL performance is so slow, it might even be faster to do the second step in Python instead of in the database.

```
names = masterQuery.filter(name__contains='test').values_list('name')
count = sum('9' in n for n in names)
```

Edit:
From your updates, I see that you are querying fields in related models, which result in multiple sql `JOIN` operations. That's likely a big reason why the query is slow.

To avoid joins, you could try something like this. The goal is to avoid doing deeply chained lookups across relations.

```
# query only RelatedModel, avoid JOIN
related_pks = RelatedModel.objects.filter(
     record_value__contains=constraint['TVAL'],
     record_attribute_type=rtypePK,
).values_list('pk', flat=True)

# list(queryset) will do a database query, resulting in a list of integers.
pks_list = list(related_pks)

# use that result to filter your main model. 
count = MainModel.objects.filter(
     formrecordattributevalue__in=pks_list
).count()
```

I'm assuming that the relation is defined as a foreign key from MainModel to RelatedModel.

Comment: I tried the value_list solution to no avail--I'm getting the same slow down. I edited the original post to reflect the coded attempt! Thanks for helping as well!

Comment: I also tried it with list() around the values list and it actually takes a little longer--in a weird way. It shortens the amount of time for the larger 100,000 result query,  but new queries that only return 50,000 result used to take ~1-2secs now take 8secs -- I'm trying to investigate some more details on the behvior

Comment: I don't think that your updated code is equivalent to the example from the docs. You are still building a massive nested query with joins (`values`). The trick is to split the process in two steps/queries. For example, filter "relatedmodel", then use those pks to filter main model. You can `print(values.query)` to get an idea of why that queryset is inefficient.

Comment: Here's the original .query result that takes 4-5 seconds using chained filters:

`SELECT base_form.id, base_form.form_type_id FROM base_form INNER JOIN base_formrecordattributevalue ON ( base_form.id = base_formrecordattributevalue.form_parent_id ) INNER JOIN base_formrecordattributevalue T5 ON ( base_form.id = T5.form_parent_id ) WHERE (base_form.form_type_id = 232  AND base_formrecordattributevalue.record_attribute_type_id = 16981  AND base_formrecordattributevalue.record_value LIKE BINARY %C%  AND T5.record_value LIKE %4H%  AND T5.record_attribute_type_id = 16986 )`

Comment: `queriedForms.filter(pk__in=list(formtype.form_set.all().filter(formrecordattributevalue__record_value__contains=constraint['TVAL'], formrecordattributevalue__record_attribute_type__pk=rtypePK).values_list('pk', flat=True))).count()`

Seems to be generally faster overall for larger queryset results, but with smaller queryset results, <10,000 it's actually a little slower than chain filtering.

Comment: The `pks_in` part is not sufficient in itself (after all, if you have a list of the pks, the final query, using only that, is redundant.). The important thing is to avoid INNER JOIN, which you get when you query across model relations. I've added another suggestion to my answer, which I hope shows what I mean.

Comment: Just got back to work this morning--I'll see if I can work it out through this suggestion! Thanks again!

Comment: I am going to have to use an INNER JOIN though--I'm using the queryset for more than just counts later in the code. I tried a test using your latest solution--which gave me wrong counts--but I know why. Regardless--I still wasn't getting a significant speed increase--because the "MainModel" in your edit that I'm doing contains 100,000+ rows--and comparing all 100,000+ by the list seemed only slightly faster to comparing a subset based on a filter. It's also possible I did it wrong, but I think for now--the list suggestion works better, even with the INNER JOIN. Thanks for your time and help!